# mysqli insert multiple rows from a loop

Tags: php

I am trying to insert multiple rows based on a loop.
This code inserts the first item from the loop only, then ignores the rest of the loop
I know the loop is counting correctly as `echo`'ing out the values outputs ok

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $count){

    foreach($html->find('.markuptag a') as $mystring){
        if(preg_match_all("|<a.*(?=href=\"([^\"]*)\")[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>|i", $mystring, $matches)){
            $a = $matches[2][0];
         }

        $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (`firstname`, `lastname`, `var_a`) VALUES ('$fistname', '$lastname', '$a')";

        $mysqli->query($query);//<< is there a better way?

    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build an array of the rows to insert, then insert them all at once. Something like this:

```
$arr = []; // array() in PHP 5.3 and older
foreach(...) {
    ...
    $arr[] = "('$fistname', '$lastname', '$a')";
}
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO mytable (`firstname`, `lastname`, `var_a`) VALUES "
    .implode(",",$arr));
```

Comment: how would this work if i need to capture the `$thisID = $mysqli->insert_id` of each of the arr?

Comment: Hmm... You could get that ID still, it should be the ID of the last row inserted, then subtract `count($arr)-1` to get the ID of the first, and work from there.